# GreenDao portability and connection

Tags: java, greendao

I have the following questions:

- It is possible to use `GreenDao` for cross platform application? For example an application that runs on desktops and also on Android.
- What alternatives exist?
- In `GreenDao` what is the package for `MasterDao`?
- Can anyone give a real example with connection and operation on database?

Comment: Asked more than a year ago, but still a great question. GreenDAO uses `Database` interface to operate with SQLite. And you can use SQLite on the desktop or backend. So, the question is, I think, in implementing this bridge, this `Database` interface.

Comment: Okay, I was wrong. It is not abstracted enough, GreenDAO uses raw Android SQLite too, so the short answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

- [ORMLite](https://ormlite.com/) is an old and well-known library supporting both JDBC and Android SQLite. But it's not SQL-centric, it's ORM; also it's reflection-based, so I don't recommend using it;
- [SQLDelight](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight) supports SQLite (JVM, Android, iOS, and more), MySQL, and more;
- it's possible to use JDBC on Android, for example, `org.sqldroid:sqldroid` driver. There's also [a Russian article about using JOOQ with Android](https://habr.com/ru/post/422303/), you can look through code blocks and just ignore the text;
- I'm developing [Lychee](https://github.com/Miha-x64/Lychee): data-binding and persistence infrastructure. `:sql` module contains both `JdbcSession` and `SqliteSession` which implement a common interface, and there are `SqliteDialect` and `PostgresDialect`, but the API is currently under construction and requires some work: it contains legacy ORM-like parts and not fully implemented SQL-centric API (see [issue #32](https://github.com/Miha-x64/Lychee/issues/32) for more info).